# Verilog: Simulation and Hardware Implementation differ in one state behaviour

Tags: verilog, simulation, state-machine, synthesis

I am currently trying to implement a UART-simulation into an FPGA. The idea is, to just cycle through predefined data (defined by byte_array_com_message_1 - 4) which will then be put out on one line (out_cross_com1). Every byte shall be sent according to a used UART standard, so by keeping the signal high while idle, set a start bit by pulling low, send 8 bit of data, send a stop bit by pulling high, then start the next frame by pulling low etc..
My toolchain is verilog, vvp, gtkwave.
EDIT: The synthesize is done by IceStudio for a Nandland GO Board.
The code I have written looks fine in gtkwave.
[image: Gtk wave Simulation. Blue Highlight: Stop bit just 1 cycle, followed by the next start-bit]
But the oscilloscope screenshot shows, that two cycles of stop-bits are being output.
[image: Oscilloscope. First falling edge is the start-bit]
Both, simulation and oscilloscope show the first two bytes to transmit which are 0xA5 and 0x33 from [0:7].
Since I am quite new to verilog and FPGAs, I don't know how to debug this error systematically.

Code Under test:

```
wire out_cross_com1;
wire state_out_0;
wire state_out_1;

wire [7:0] byte_array_com_message_1 [0:31];
wire [7:0] byte_array_com_message_2 [0:31];
wire [7:0] byte_array_com_message_3 [0:31];
wire [7:0] byte_array_com_message_4 [0:31];
reg [2:0] bit_position;
reg [4:0] byte_position;
reg [1:0] message_index;
reg [1:0] uart_statemachine;
reg [1:0] uart_statemachine_next;
reg signal_out_cross_com1;

assign byte_array_com_message_1[0] = 8'hA5;
assign byte_array_com_message_1[1] = 8'h33;
//assign byte_array_com_message_1[2} = ....;

localparam
    uart_idle = 2'b00,
    uart_start = 2'b01,
    uart_transmit = 2'b10,
    uart_stop = 2'b11;

localparam
    message_1 = 2'b00,
    message_2 = 2'b01,
    message_3 = 2'b10,
    message_4 = 2'b11;

assign clk_out = clk;
assign out_cross_com1 = signal_out_cross_com1;
assign state_out_0 = uart_statemachine[0];
assign state_out_1 = uart_statemachine[1];

// output
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(rst == 1) begin
        signal_out_cross_com1 <= 1;
    end else begin
        case(uart_statemachine)
            uart_idle:
            begin
                signal_out_cross_com1 <= 1;
            end
            uart_start:
            begin
                signal_out_cross_com1 <= 0;
            end
            uart_transmit:
                case(message_index)
                    message_1:
                    begin
                        signal_out_cross_com1 <= byte_array_com_message_1[byte_position][bit_position];
                    end
                    message_2:
                    begin
                        signal_out_cross_com1 <= byte_array_com_message_2[byte_position][bit_position];
                    end
                    message_3:
                    begin
                        signal_out_cross_com1 <= byte_array_com_message_3[byte_position][bit_position];
                    end
                    message_4:
                    begin
                        signal_out_cross_com1 <= byte_array_com_message_4[byte_position][bit_position];
                    end
                endcase
            uart_stop:
            begin
                signal_out_cross_com1 <= 1;
            end
        endcase
    end

end

// update bit position
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(rst == 1) begin
        bit_position <= 3'b000;
        byte_position <= 5'b00000;
        message_index <= 2'b00;
    end else begin
        case(uart_statemachine)
            uart_idle:
            begin
                bit_position <= 3'b000;
                byte_position <= 5'b00000;
                message_index <= 2'b00;
            end
            uart_start:
            begin
                bit_position <= 3'b000;
                byte_position <= byte_position;
                message_index <= message_index;
            end
            uart_transmit:
            begin
                if(bit_position == 7) begin
                    bit_position <= 3'b000;
                    if(byte_position == 31) begin
                        byte_position <= 5'b00000;
                        if(message_index == 3) begin
                            message_index <= 2'b00;
                        end else begin
                            message_index <= message_index + 1;
                        end
                    end else begin
                        byte_position <= byte_position + 1;
                    end
                end else begin
                    bit_position <= (bit_position + 1);
                end
            end
            uart_stop:
            begin
                bit_position <= 3'b000;
                byte_position <= byte_position;
                message_index <= message_index;
            end
        endcase
    end
end

// Statemachine
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(rst == 1) begin
        uart_statemachine <= uart_idle;
    end else begin
        uart_statemachine <= uart_statemachine_next;
    end
end

// Determine next state
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(rst == 1) begin
        uart_statemachine_next <= uart_idle;
    end else begin
        case(uart_statemachine_next)
            uart_idle:
            begin
                uart_statemachine_next <= uart_start;
            end
            uart_start:
            begin
                uart_statemachine_next <= uart_transmit;
            end
            uart_transmit:
            begin
                // end of byte. Stop bit
                if(bit_position == 7) begin
                    uart_statemachine_next <= uart_stop;
                // stay until end of byte
                end else begin
                    uart_statemachine_next <= uart_transmit;
                end
            end
            uart_stop:
            begin
                uart_statemachine_next <= uart_start;
            end
        endcase
    end
end
```

Test bench:

```
`include "cross_com_sim.v"
`timescale 1ns/100ps

module cross_com_sim_tb;
    reg clk;
    reg rst;
    wire out_cross_com1;
    wire out_cross_com2;
    wire clk_out;
    cross_com_sim DUT(.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .out_cross_com1(out_cross_com1));

    initial
    begin
        $dumpfile("cross_com_sim_dump.vcd");
        $dumpvars;
    end

    initial
    begin
        clk = 1;
        forever #1 clk = ~clk;
    end

    initial
    begin
        rst = 1;
        #6;
        rst = 0;
        #4000;
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "next state" block should be written in combinational logic style so the state machine can run correctly. Like this:

```
// Determine next state
always @*
begin
  case(uart_statemachine)
    uart_idle:  uart_statemachine_next = uart_start;
    uart_start: uart_statemachine_next = uart_transmit;
    uart_transmit: ...
    ...
  endcase
end
```

By the way, if reset signal comes from a source that is not synchronized with clock, like a push button on FPGA board.
It should be synchronized with clock to prevent from meta-
stable. Like this:

```
// rst_in is the reset signal input
// rst is the synchronized reset
reg rst_meta;
always @( posedge clk or posedge rst_in )
  if ( rst_in )
    { rst, rst_meta } <= 2'b11;
  else
    { rst, rst_meta } <= { rst_meta, 1'b0 };
```

Comment: Your solution worked, although I do not understand, why. Also, so far I did not understand the reset synchronization.

Comment: It's weird that I've run the original code with VCS and got the same waveform as oscilloscope measured. May be the simulator issue.

Comment: @sharvian Hm that's really weird.

Comment: @user44791 If the reset signal comes from outside, the edge of reset signal may appear at any moment with respect to clock. Which may cause setup time or hold time violation. So it would be better using a synchronized reset, no matter the DFF takes sync or async reset. The synchronization also applies to UART RX signal.